# On submit event triggering when it shouldn't be jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the submitting of POST forms to use AJAX. This works, but unfortunately it also appears to be triggering for GET requests. Does anyone know why?

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[method=post]', $(this).ajaxForm({...}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you [preventing default](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the click action?  here is an example that shows that your first and second arguments in the **.on()** method are functioning correctly.  Your third argument should be structured like the snippet so that an anonymous function does some form handling.

```js
$(document).ready(function (argument) {

    $(document).on('submit', 'form[method=post]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.status').html('post')
 });

 $(document).on('submit', 'form[method=get]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.status').html('get')
 });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="status">click button to change this text</div>
<form method="post"><button type="submit">Post</button></form>
<form method="get"><button type="submit">Get</button></form>
```

Comment: It turned out that my code that I provided for the post was fine, but I needed to put ```event.preventDefault()``` in the handler for the get request.